# How to solve this error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to Iterator<String>"

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8

I am new in java8 and spark, where I am trying to execute simple flatmap transformation program in java, But I am facing some error in flatmap transformation in second last line `Arrays.asList(e.split(" ")));` and error is

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<String>` to `Iterator<String>`

What is the appropriate solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
 import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
 import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
 import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

 public class FlatMapExample {
           public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new 
          SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("filter 
          transformation");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);



    // Parallelized with 2 partitions
    JavaRDD<String> rddX = sc.parallelize(
            Arrays.asList("spark rdd example", "sample example"),
            2);

    // map operation will return List of Array in following case
    JavaRDD<String[]> rddY = rddX.map(e -> e.split(" "));

    List<String[]> listUsingMap = rddY.collect();
    for(int i = 0; i < listUsingMap.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("list.."+StringUtils.join(listUsingMap.get(i)));
    }
    //System.out.println("listUsingMap..."+listUsingMap.collect());

    // flatMap operation will return list of String in following case
    JavaRDD<String> rddY2 = rddX.flatMap(e -> Arrays.asList(e.split(" ")));
    List<String> listUsingFlatMap = rddY2.collect();
}
```

}

Comment: [`List.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator--)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have specified that you are using at least version `2.0` where `FlatMapFunction::call` returns actually an `Iterator` and not `Iterable` (in 1.6 this is the case for example). Thus, your `rddX.flatMap` is suppose to return an `Iterator<String>`, while `Arrays.asList(e.split(" "))` returns a `List<String>`.

But there is `List::iterator` that you can use, as :

```
 rddX.flatMap(e -> Arrays.asList(e.split(" ")).iterator())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to explain little more, hope would be helpful to you and others who face the same problem.

**`rdd.flatMap((e -> Arrays.asList(e.split(" ")))`** is correct in spark 1.6 and 
in spark 2.0.

**`rddX.flatMap(e -> Arrays.asList(e.split(" ")).iterator())`** is correct.

Below is the flatMap method signature, which takes FlatMapFunction as an parameter.

**`public <U> JavaRDD<U> flatMap(FlatMapFunction<T, U> f)`**

**Spark 1.6 FlatMapFunction**

call method returns Iterable

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FlatMapFunction<T, R> extends Serializable {
   Iterable<R> call(T t) throws Exception
}
```

**Spark 2.0 FlatMapFunction**

call method returns Iterator

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FlatMapFunction<T, R> extends Serializable {
    Iterator<R> call(T var1) throws Exception;
}
```

**So, which means flatMap method in spark 1.6 needs a lambda expression (java 8)  which  returns Iterable while in Spark 2.0 requred return type is Iterator.**

Now,

rddX.flatMap(e -> Arrays.asList(e.split(" ")))

`Arrays.asList(e.split(" "))` returns a java.util.List and List is an Iterable.

*List implements Collection*

```
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>
```

*Collection implements  Iterable.*

```
public interface Collection<E> extends Iterable<E>
```

So in Spark 1.6 `Arrays.asList()` works fine but In Spark 2.0 need to further call iterator() on this List to get Iterator.

```
Arrays.asList(e.split(" ")).iterator()
```

Comment: well explained.